# mysql query migrating away from sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have the following working query, but I'm looking to move away from the sub query approach.

```
select t0.emp_id, t1.first_name, t1.last_name

from employee_profile As t0 left join user_profile as t1 on t0.user_profile_id = t1.id

where t0.emp_id not in (select t4.emp_id from time_sheet as t4 where t4.ts_end_date = '2014-10-08')
```

There is 1301 employee profiles
There is 337 that do not have time_sheets for end date 2014-10-08

This works perfectly thus far.

Now I'm trying to migrate away from the sub query and into a join. I've tried the following without success.

With this query, I get the complete opposite of what I'm looking for which is 964 results.

```
select t0.emp_id, t1.first_name, t1.last_name, t3.emp_id

from employee_profile As t0 left join user_profile as t1 on t0.user_profile_id = t1.id 
left join time_sheet as t3 on t0.id = t3.employee_profile_id
```

I've also tried the following using where conditions and got 0 results

1.

```
where t3.ts_end_date = '2014-10-08'
and t3.employee_profile_id is null
```

2.

```
where t3.ts_end_date = '2014-10-08'
and t3.id is null
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out

```
select t0.emp_id, t1.first_name, t1.last_name, t3.emp_id

from employee_profile As t0 left join user_profile as t1 on t0.user_profile_id = t1.id 
left join time_sheet as t3 on t0.id = t3.employee_profile_id and t3.ts_end_date = '2014-10-08'

where t3.employee_profile_id is null
```